# Correct Format for String to Date?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I m sorry stackoverflow is full of dateformatter questions but i m having a really hard time to get a string into a `NSDate`.

This is the String i receive:

> 2014-12-22T06:49:40+0000

And this is how i m trying to format it and get it to a `NSDate`:

```
NSString *time = @"2014-12-22T06:49:40+0000";
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'"];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString:time];
```

Unfortunately *myDate* is always `nil`.
Am i missing somtheing or is my formatting simply wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSSSSSSZ"

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but it's still nil.

Comment: OK, i got it, i just had to remove the "SSSSSSS". Thanks for that hint :)

Answer (score 1):

You've wrapped your final `Z` in single quotes, which means you want it to be a literal `Z` character, but no such character exists in your time string. Removing the single quotes means it would be looking for a timezone offset, like you want.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I kind of had trouble with a lot of parts of that, Owen's answer made it a bit clearer what to do, but thanks for your response too.